# Realme 5 (android 10) trying to boot into fastboot mode

Tags: fastboot, android-10, realme

I can't boot into fastboot mode, no key combination works, I also tried with adb command 'adb reboot bootloader' then fastboot logo flashes for a second and it boots into system!
I contacted Realme customer executive and they said there is no fastboot on this device!!!
What does that mean?
Is there any work around?

Comment: Power off your phone first, then press volume up+ power or volume down +power and it'll boot into fast mode. If not, try vol up/down + home + power button. See if any of these works

Comment: *"there is no fastboot mode on this device"* **means** fastboot mode is disabled intentionally. nothing you can do

Comment: https://c.realme.com/in/post-details/1184729509568446464